# What is the best and easier IDE/programing language for creating games for android?

Tags: java, c#, android, python

I have question:

> What is the best and easiest IDE/programing language for creating games
>   for android?

(I heard about Java - Android SDK, C# - xamarin, C# - unity, Scratch)

I think I need more info in this field and I will glad for any answer.

(Is there something with Python and is it easier or more complex than others...?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very subjective question, but Unity sounds like what you're looking for. It has support for Boo as a language (although it's not at the forefront of Unity usage). Boo isn't Python, but is similar enough for you to carry on your knowledge of Python with you, and Unity is a solid engine for both 2D and 3D games that abstracts away a lot of the lower level details between different platforms. It's packaged with Mono Develop, which works as an IDE. I personally prefer UnityVS + Visual Studio (For C# you don't need UnityVS unless you want to debug in VS). Also watch out for the upcoming free release of UnityVS.